# Pass object value into each href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Hi I am trying to dynamically create anchor links.

The links themselves are created using a handle bars template

```
{{#each anchor-links}}
<li><a href="">{{anchor-name}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

This way the user can easily define the front end name value for the links using the anchor-name property and control the number of links with yml data.

For this example That bit of code renders three links. The HTML output looks like so:

```
<li><a href="">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Section 3</a></li>
```

I am getting the href values by finding all section elements with an id (this is what should go in the href) and iterating through that array:

```
this.$links = this.$el.find('li a');
this.$destination = $('section[id]').map(function(){ return this.id });

createLinks(){
      let i = 0;

      this.$links.attr('href', '#' + this.$destination[i]);
      for (i = 0; i < this.$destination.length; i++){
          console.log(this.$destination[i]);
      }
  }
```

However the output I am getting looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#section-1">Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#section-1">Section 3</a></li>
```

and I want it to look like this based on the values returned from finding the sections with id's

```
<li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#section-2">Section 3</a></li>
```

Any help fixing this is appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this in the templating, you can get the index in the loop with `{{@index}}`

Comment: @adeneo it would but for this issue the client is not not looking at my templating rather the pure html/js output

Comment: Your client wants you to band-aid the markup rather than fixing the generation in the first place?

Comment: Without trying to go into the whole back story this previously was a full front end working solution. However they need to the pure js/jquery so it can be integrated into their content editor. I'm just trying to get this to work / under the issue of why the values are the same in the hrefs. Thanks.

Comment: You're setting the attribute outside the loop, so why would `i` be anything other than `0` ?

Comment: @adeneo thanks for that, even if I put the attr in the for loop the result is the same

let i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < this.$destination.length; i++){
    this.$links.attr('href', '#' + this.$destination[i]);
  
   }

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2w5fcymf/

Comment: `this.$links` is **all** the links, so now you're setting **all** the links on each iteration, and end up with all of them having the last value

Comment: @adeno ah I see, would jquerys each() work with the syntax I have now? I'm getting an error when I try and implement cant read property of 0 

let i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < this.$destination.length; i++){
    this.$links.each(function(i, el){
     this.attr('href', '#' + this.$destination[i])
    });
   }

Comment: The problem with that code, is that `this` inside the callback function for `each` isn't what you think it is, it's no longer the `this` that has a `destinitation` property, hence why I used variables in the fiddle

Comment: @adeneo ! I see what you mean now, thanks your solution is working